# Problemas em converter inteiro para string (stringstream) c++

Tags: c++, string, cast

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int n, aux;
    string hexa="";
    stringstream hexa_aux;

    cin >> n;
    while(n != 0){
        aux = n % 16;
        n/=16;
        switch (aux){
            case 10:
                hexa+="A";
                break;

            case 11:
                hexa+="B";
                break;

            case 12:
                hexa+="C";
                break;

            case 13:
                hexa+="D";
                break;

            case 14:
                hexa+="E";
                break;

            case 15:
                hexa+="F";
                break;

            default:
                hexa_aux << aux;
                hexa+=hexa_aux.str();
                break;
        }
    }
    for(int i = hexa.length()-1; i>=0; i--){
        cout << hexa[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Estou com problemas em converter um número inteiro para `string`, quando a entrada é 36, o resultado certo deveria ser 24, mas o valor acaba saindo 244, entre outros valores.

O problema é com a conversão?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro está de facto nesta linha:

```
hexa+=hexa_aux.str();
```

Que devia de atribuir apenas, e não concatenar, assim:

```
hexa=hexa_aux.str();
```

Que já ira fazer o programa funcionar. Apesar disso este pode ser simplificado, utilizando a tabela ASCII para chegar aos caracteres que interessam, assim como na impressão de forma inversa:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int n, aux;
    stringstream hexa_aux;

    cin >> n;

    while(n != 0){
        aux = n % 16;
        n/=16;

        if (aux >9){ //concatenar as letras
            hexa_aux << (char)(aux + 'A'- 10);
        }
        else { //concatenar os números
            hexa_aux << (char)(aux + '0');
        }
    }

    string aux_str = hexa_aux.str();
    cout<<string(aux_str.rbegin(), aux_str.rend()); //imprimir invertido

    return 0;
}
```

Para perceber melhor a lógica aplicada à construção dos caracteres, é necessário olhar para a tabela *[ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif)*. Se olharmos para a parte dos números vemos:

```
48  '0' zero
49  '1' um
50  '2' dois
51  '3' três
52  '4' quatro
53  '5' cinco
54  '6' seis
55  '7' sete
56  '8' oito
57  '9' nove
```

Em que a primeira coluna é o valor inteiro de cada letra. Logo se tivermos o número `0` e queremos a letra correspondente basta somar `48` que ficamos com `'0'`. De `1` para `49` (`'1'`) basta na mesma somar `48`. E `48` é exatamente o valor do `'0'`. Logo

```
num + '0'
```

Ou

```
num + 48
```

Chega ao caractere que se pretende. O que explica esta parte:

```
hexa_aux << (char)(aux + '0');
```

Para a parte de `A` a `F` é o mesmo principio mas não podemos diretamente somar o `'A'` porque o numero que temos para transformar em `A` é o `10`, e por isso iriamos parar a 10ª letra do abecedário. Nesse caso é necessário descontabilizar esse bocado retirando `10`:

```
hexa_aux << (char)(aux + 'A'- 10);
```

[Veja a funcionar no Ideone](http://ideone.com/yjDQJC)

Answer (score 0):

O seu problema é que a `stringstream hexa_aux` precisa ser reinicializada a cada interação do `switch`. Ela tá lembrando dos valores anteriores. O modo mais fácil de resolver é declará-la no escopo da opção `default`. Ou seja,

```
default:
     stringstream hexa_aux;  // Declare aqui, assim ela se reinicializa
                             // a cada chamada do switch
     hexa_aux << aux;
     hexa+=hexa_aux.str();
     break;
```

Uma segunda alternativa, é esquecer do `stringstream` e usar a função `std::to_string()`. Exemplo:

```
default:
     hexa+=std::to_string(aux);
     break;
```